# wildcards in asp.net mvc routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i'm using asp.net mvc with vs2008 and IIS7.
What i want to accomplish is that all requests that START WITH 'summer' are routed to the same controller.
'till now i've built tons of routes, but they were all for one path (with parameters offcourse) but this one must route:
www.mysite.com/summercity
www.mysite.com/summermadness
www.mysite.com/summer
www.mysite.com/summerweather

to the same controller.

the only solution i've come up with is 'summer*', but that didn't work :)

Michel

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use:

```
/Summer{*Data}
```

Comment: wicked! didn't know the {} notation.